# Length of primary key for Long data type in Java (and Hibernate)?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

```
log(2^32) / log(10) =~ 9.63295986126
log(10^0.63295986126) / log(2) =~ 2.10264714605 > 2 bit

log(2^64) / log(10) =~  19.2659197225
log(10^0.2659197225) / log(2) =~ 0.883366197155 < 2 bit
```

As you can see 9 digits for `Integer` doesn't lead to negative values in `Integer` type.

But 19 digits in `Long` can cause sign overflow... I usually see `NUMBER(18)` as type of ID column...

Is it possible to have problem with mapping `NUMBER(19)` to `Long` in Hibernate?

Comment: Can not understand: how length of column in table in oracle influences on possibility of gaining negative numbers in ID from Hibernate?

Comment: `log(9'999'999'999'999'999'999) / log(2) =~ 63.1166338029` so you can't hold this value in 63 bits (note there are 19 of `9`). So sign bit will be used... And possibly Hibernate throw error. That is a question...

Comment: Ok, that's an answer: sign bit could be used. So what's the question?

Comment: I am not native English speaker: *Is it possible to have problem with mapping NUMBER(19) to Long in Hibernate?*

Answer (score 2):

Do not use Long - it's intended for numbers. You never multiply, add, subtract PKs. (you probably even never sort them). For Oracle datatype NUMBER use either oracle.sql.NUMBER or java.math.BigDecimal.

Comment: Hm... Never use `String` because I never concatenate/search them. But you are right that for *big NUMBER* I have to use java.math.BigDecimal for id field! +1